# Integrating Text and Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

```
Now I need to put some text and some button in the custom UITableViewCell.
I hope the text and button are continuous. And the text is colorful.
Such as: It will take you(black color) (a clock button)2 minutes(yellow color).
I have used UIWebView into Cell load the text and button. But the roll has some problem.
I have not any idea.
Thanks!
```

Answer (score 5):

Make a Custom Table Cell by inheriting UITableViewCell and add button and text in the Custom Table Cell.

Comment: But I hope the text and button are continuous. The button is follow close below of the text statment. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

For a basic idea on `UITableViewCell` customization

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Comment: But I hope the text and button are continuous. The button is follow close below of the text statment. And the text isn't fixed.How should I solve it?